# jenkins Publish over SSH error: connection timed out

Tags: jenkins

When I click the Test configuration button, tip is under testing，the last thorw

```
jenkins.plugins.publish_over.BapPublisherException: Failed to connect and initialize SSH connection. 
Message: [Failed to connect session for config [userName]. 
Message [java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect]]



environment: windows 10 
jenkins version: 2.60.3
```

the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Looks like permission issue on the `.ssh` directory of your remote machine. Try giving it `drwx------` permission i.e `chmod 700` to your `.ssh` directory.